# Prove that $(f\circ \alpha)''$ is not a tangent vector, where $\alpha$ is a diferentiable curve on a manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M,\Psi)$ be a manifold with a $C^k$ atlas, and let $\alpha: I\subset \mathbb{R}\mapsto M$ be a $C^k$ curve in $M$ with $\alpha(0)=p\in M$. The curve $\alpha$ defines a tangent vector at $p$:  $$\dot{\alpha}_p (f)=\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ \alpha)|_{t=0}$$

How can I prove that $A(f)=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(f\circ \alpha)|_p$ is not a tangent vector?
I tried supposing the existence of $\mu(t)$ such that, making $A(f)=(f\circ \alpha)''|_{t=0}$, the following is satisfied:

$$\dot{\mu}_p=A.$$

The above approach has led me nowhere though, since $(f\circ\mu)'|_{t=0}=(f\circ\alpha)''|_{t=0}$ does not imply $(f\circ\mu)=(f\circ\alpha)'+C$ as the derivatives need not be equal anywhere besides $t=0$. 
I also tried using different functions $f$ (in particular $f=x^i$ the $i$-th projection) to obtain a contradiction, but this also proved unsatisfactory.

Any hints as to the direction in which this proof can be completed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is "wrong"; you are not supposed to prove that $(f\circ \alpha)''$ is not a tangent vector; that statement makes no sense as $f\circ\alpha$ is a scalar along $I$. What you are asked to show is that there does not exist a tangent vector $A$, depending on $\alpha$, such that $A(f) = (f\circ \alpha)''$.

Comment: I should have been more clear in the statement of the problem (I just edited the question). But the non-existence of such $A$ is what I'm stuck at: I want to show that there is no curve $\mu$ such that $\mu'=A$ (both functions of $f$)

Comment: You mean that $\mu$ and $A$ both depend on $\alpha$. They cannot depend on $f$ since you are constructing a geometric object that works for all $f$.

Comment: Yes, they cannot depend on $f$, perhaps I could've been more careful with the way I wrote the statement; I just wanted to emphasize that tangent vectors take $f$ as input, so there would be no misunderstandings as to what is a scalar, an element of the manifold or a tangent vector. In this problem $\alpha$ is an arbitrary $C^k$ curve in $M$ (with the appropriate conditions) over which I have no control.

Comment: I've given you hints below. It is up to you to try it and let me know if there is something you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Take a coordinate chart around $p$ such that $p$ is mapped to the origin. In this coordinate chart consider the function $f(x) = |x|^2$.

1. Let $v$ be any tangent vector at $p$, what do you know about $v(f)$?
2. Let $\alpha$ be the curve $t \mapsto (t, 0, 0,\ldots, 0)$ in this chart. What is $(f\circ\alpha)''$?
3. Given an arbitrary $\alpha$ with $\alpha'(0) \neq 0$, can you generalise the result in step 2 to find a function $f$ having the requisite properties?

Comment: Sorry I haven't had the chance to use the computer.
The function $f(x)$ should be defined on $M$, as tangent vectors take functions from $U\subset M \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. What I could do is take $\varphi$ chart with $p\in \text{Dom}\varphi$ and construct $f(x)=|\varphi(x)-\varphi(p)|^2$

Comment: Given that $p$ is mapped to the origin, the function $f(m)=|\varphi(m)|^2$, when plugged into any tangent vector $v$, yields $0$ for any $v$. In 2, when computing $(f\circ \alpha)''$ for the described curve, I also get a constant times the first component of $\varphi(p)$, which, in this case, is also zero. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong things here, but I can't conclude anything from this.

Comment: You did 2 wrong. Try it first in Euclidean space. $f\circ \alpha(t) = t^2$ so its second derivative is exactly 2 which is nonzero. Now try to figure out where your mistake came from.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did the calculations for both the function $|\varphi(x)|^2, (\varphi(p)=0)$ and $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(p)|^2$ and in both cases I get nonzero values in 2. How do I conclude from this the result?

Comment: Suppose there exists a tangent vector $v$ such that for every smooth function $(f\circ \alpha)'' = v(f)$. You have however found a smooth function for which you can explicitly compute both sides of the "equality". What are the values?